# Java simple chat client & server Running Problems

Tags: java, .net, io

I'm making a simple java server & client for Educational purposes while finishing learning the Connections chapters in java language, and I had several problems while running the program, so i would be glad if I could get any kind of help to solve my problem, I had a main problems while running it

Problem : A text doesn't get sent both sides, I have made 2 clients, when I send text from client 1 for exemple to client 2, its all good, but vise-versa it doesn't

Sourse Code: main class

```
public class Start {    
public static void main(String [] args) {

    chatserver server = new chatserver();
    server.go();

    chatclient chat = new chatclient();
    chat.go();

    chatclient2 chat2 = new chatclient2();
    chat2.go();

    }
}
```

First Client class:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;

import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;


import java .awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class chatclient {
JTextArea incoming;
JTextField outgoing;
BufferedReader reader;
PrintWriter writer;
Socket sock;
public void go() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Chat Client V.1");

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel() ;
    incoming = new JTextArea(15,50);
    incoming.setLineWrap(true);
    incoming.setWrapStyleWord(true) ;
    incoming.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane qScroller = new JScrollPane(incoming) ;
    qScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    qScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    outgoing = new JTextField(30);
    JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");

    sendButton.addActionListener(new sendz());
    mainPanel.add (qScroller) ;
    mainPanel.add(outgoing);
    mainPanel.add(sendButton);
    connectinsetup();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new reader());
    thread.start();
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,mainPanel);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}

public void connectinsetup() {
    try{
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",5000);
    InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());      
    reader = new BufferedReader(stream);
    writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("Connection Established");
    }
catch(IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}   
}

public class sendz implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try{

            writer.println(outgoing.getText());
            writer.flush();

        }

        catch(Exception exz){
            exz.printStackTrace();
        }
    outgoing.setText("");
    outgoing.requestFocus();
    }

}

public class reader implements Runnable{

    public void run() {
String msg;
try{
while ( (msg = reader.readLine() ) != null) {

incoming.append(msg + "\n");

  }
}   

catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
                   }    
                     }  
                                   }  


                                              }
```

Server Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class chatserver {
    PrintWriter writer;

    public void go() {

        try{
            ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(5000);
        while(true) {   
        Socket serversocket = socket.accept();
        Thread thread  = new Thread(new clienthandler(serversocket));
        thread.start();
         writer = new PrintWriter(serversocket.getOutputStream());



                    }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
                              }

                        } // end go method

    public class clienthandler implements Runnable {
Socket sock;
BufferedReader reader;
        public clienthandler( Socket socks) {
            try{
            sock = socks;
            InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(socks.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(stream);   
            }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
                            }   
                                           }

        public void run() {

            String msg;
        try{
            while((msg = reader.readLine())!= null ) {

            tellall(msg);
            }   
           }
            catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();   
                               }                                         

                         }

                                                      } //end clienthandler class

public void tellall(String text){

    String msgall = text;

    try{
    writer.println(msgall);
    writer.flush();
      }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
                       }

                                } //end tellall method




                                          }//end chatserver
```

And this is the Exceptions i get guys:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at test.chatserver.go(chatserver.java:12)
at test.Start.main(Start.java:12)
```

Comment: Please can you post any exceptions being thrown along with its stack traces?

Comment: Of Course, when running I only get this line of exception on the console: at test.Start.main(Start.java:8)

Comment: Can I get some help ?

Comment: I'm sorry I need the FULL stack trace, that exception message doesn't help at all

Comment: how do i get the full stack trace sir ? because thats the only msg of exception i get on console

Comment: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at test.chatserver.go(chatserver.java:12)
 at test.Start.main(Start.java:12)
Connection Established
Connection Established

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope to be helpful, I would say it has some bugs in your code such as:

```
chatclient chat = new chatclient();
chat.go();

chatclient2 chat2 = new chatclient2();
chat2.go();
```

You dont have any chatclient2, you should do:

```
chatclient chat = new chatclient();
chat.go();

chatclient chat2 = new chatclient();
chat2.go();
```

Otherwise, if you dont put the server in a different thread, the application will be frozen as it will be waiting for clients to connect (and the beginning of customers is below) is solved as easy as:

```
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            chatserver server = new chatserver();
            server.go();
        }
    }.start();
```

and in response to your question of why only text appears in one of the clients is because when you do on the server:

```
Socket serversocket = socket.accept();
Thread thread = new Thread(new clienthandler(serversocket));
thread.start();
writer = new PrintWriter(serversocket.getOutputStream());
```

each time a client connects, the 'writer' is overwritten with the last client socket (Each client has its own socket and with which we can communicate with he)

You can fix it doing for example an array of different writer with sockets ..

Greetings, I hope to be helpful = D

Comment: I'm feeling like crying right know dude, you have no idea what i have been through trying to solve these bugs all by my self( hard task for a beginner in java) i really appreciate your help man , a Big Thanx <3

Answer (score 0):

The *BindException* is thrown because the port is already in use.

There could be 2 reasons for that:

1. A *Socket* continues to run even when your program has already been terminated if you do not manually call `.close()`.

   The port is used by another service (for example web-server, database-server, ...)

I suspect option 1 is reason for your particular Exception. Just try another port or manually kill the java-background-task and then try running your program again (and close the sockets this time properly).

**When to close the Sockets:**
At first i would add a method `shutdown()` to both the client and the server. In these methods you just close all socket-instances you have, like for example here (you may need some `catch`-blocks though):

```
public void shutdown() {
    serverSocket.close();
    /* close other sockets here */   
}
```

Then you add a `WindowListener` to both of the client-GUIs and do in `windowClosing()`:

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
    client.shutdown();
}
```

For closing the server you could add the following code to the `main`-method:

```
System.out.println("Press Enter to stop the server ...");
System.in.read(); // wait for an "Enter"-press in the console

server.shutdown();
```

When closing a connected *Socket*, some Exceptions will probably be thrown on the other end of the connection. So don't forget to put appropriate `catch`-blocks there.